# Clarification needed regarding map/reduce jobs to computer average of dataset?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning map/reduce, I was working on the problem of computing mean of all the values in a particular column of the dataset.

All of the solutions I have seen so far on the do something along the lines of this

> Dataset
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
>
> map job: generate key,value pairs with key  as 1
> (1,1)
> (1,2)
> (1,3)
> (1,3)
> (1,4)

Now since key is same for the map job's output, all of them will be sent to one reducer, over there we can do the calculation sum/count

However, my question is that, is it intuitive to have same key for all entries? Isn't the purpose of map/reduce to split the jobs so that we can have them running concurrently? Doesn't having the same key for all the map's out defeat the purpose of the map/reduce?

Is this the algorithm to compute the average the most efficient one? or Can it be improved further?

Answer (score 0):

The input data to map reduce will be split based on the size of your input data. A mapper will run for each of the splits and these mapper will run concurrently. Once all the mappers are completed the reducers will be triggered  based on the output keys from the mapper. The number of reducers can be set manually or by default partitioner takes care of it.

In your use case you want compute the average of the dataset for which giving same key for all the mapper output will be correct. If the size of the input dataset is more automatically more than a single mapper will be triggered and all will run concurrently.